# Same origin host, different ports in JS

Tags: javascript, dom, same-origin-policy

for the two hosts

```
http://1.com.local/
http://2.com.local:8080/
```

how can I use `document.domain` to enable DOM-Manipulation between the two? If i set both to `com.local` it doesn't work, because the 2nd host then gets the domain `com.local:8080`.

When I try to set the domain of the first one to `com.local:8080` manually, the port is just snipped of and the domain remains `com.local`.

How can I enable DOM-Manipulation in this situation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot. Sorry - same origin is including the [ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

You can use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) and ajax to copy some stuff from one server to the other if you enable this.

Comment: By random chance I found out that if I use localhost:8x for my api server then I don't get the CORS error. If I use my standard 'safe' ports like 1000+ then I do get the CORS error. I haven't found any documentation online that discusses this but it works reliably for localhost testing purposes to get around the CORS error.

Comment: Same origin is including ports so if you go from localhost:// to localhost:1000// you are going from port 80 to port 1000 and that is cross origin

Comment: When using port 8x it isn't applying the CORS policy for localhost. For example localhost:1023 can call localhost:85 with no CORS enforcement. If I switch the api to a non port 8x then CORS policy is enforced.

Comment: Ok - great. I am surprised

Comment: Same here. It seems pretty random. I googled it try to find something to back it up but I found nothing. Anyway, at work some of us are using port 8x now and it's working fine. Haven't tested it with other browsers though.