# Angular $resource doesn't change method

Tags: angularjs, couchdb, httprequest

I'm trying to configure a simple service with Angular.js and Couchdb

```
var App = angular.module('myapp', ['ngResource'], function(){});

App.factory('products', ['$resource', function($resource) { 

  var Products = $resource(
      'http://localhost\\:5984/products/_all_docs',
      {},
      { all: { method: 'GET'} }
  );

  return {
    all: function() {
        return Products.all();
    }
  };
}]);
```

When I call `products.all()` from my controller always I get

### Request headers

```
OPTIONS /productos/_all_docs HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5984
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, origin, x-requested-with
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:8000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

### Response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: CouchDB/1.2.1 (Erlang OTP/R14B04)
Date: Tue, 29 Jan 2013 22:15:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 69
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST

Request URL:http://localhost:5984/productos/_all_docs
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
```

I can not imagine why it sends an OPTIONS method when I haven't declared that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OPTIONS` method comes from doing a cross origin request. See [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/jquery-why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-insted-of-a-get-request). Even though both the host and the request is to `localhost`, the ports are different (5984, 8000). See [Same origin host, different ports in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714135/same-origin-host-different-ports-in-js).

Comment: So how do I sidestep it?