# Why my request POST by $resource is an OPTIONS

Tags: angularjs

The code I'm using is the following, in coffeescipt :

```
request_with_token =
  get:
    method: "JSONP",
    params:
      token: app["token"]
  save:
    method: "POST",
    params:
      token: app["token"]

$rootScope.API = "http://0.0.0.0:5200/1.0"

$scope.ajaxAccountUpdate = $resource($rootScope.API + "/account/update.json",
  { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, request_with_token )

user = $scope.user
$scope.ajaxAccountUpdate.save user, (resource) ->
  $scope.show_message(resource)
```

But in my Log I have an OPTIONS instead a POST

```
[07/Feb/2013 16:50:48] "OPTIONS /1.0/account/update?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&token=mytoken HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593130/angular-resource-dont-change-method/14593360#14593360

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you're making a request to a different website from where the HTML is served, resulting in a 'Cross-Origin Resource Sharing' CORS pre-flight check. This is a security feature:

For more information: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: +1. Make sure the URL you're viewing the site in your browser at matches the URL in `$rootScope.API`.