# localstorage same origin policy in IE

Tags: local-storage, same-origin-policy

I would like to ask if it is possible to create two different localstorage in IE with the same origin but different port? I am aware that IE has this exception for same origin policy but we want to achieve this like the current behavior of chrome. Our project has two environment resides in same origin but in different port eg. test.com:8006 and test.com:8007 for release versions. One user can access previous release in one browser tab while another user can use current release in the other tab.

If this is not possible at all, can you let me know what are the work arounds? or how did you handle this scneario?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same origin host, different ports in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714135/same-origin-host-different-ports-in-js)

Answer (score 0):

Different ports means different origins.
So all the CORS policy for local storage apply for websites with different port.

As for a solution to your problem, there is not direct way to do it but there are a couple of workarounds mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177803/can-html5-databases-and-localstorage-be-shared-across-subdomains) post